# jQuery - how to run one event while delaying another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm a bit of a jQuery newbie, so forgive me if this seems a bit simple! I am setting up a sliding header system, which works very much like an accordion menu, however the links to open and close the elements are in a different part of the HTML, so all the accordion tutorials I found didn't work.

I have got this so far: HTML:

```
<div class="drawer" id="drawer_about"></div>
<div class="drawer" id="drawer_contact"></div>
<div class="drawer" id="drawer_hire"></div>
<div class="drawer" id="drawer_social"></div>

...

<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#" class="show_hide_about"><span>About Me</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="show_hide_contact"><span>Get In Touch</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="show_hide_hire"><span>Hire Me</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="show_hide_social"><span>Social Networks</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#drawer_about").hide();
        $("#drawer_contact").hide();
        $("#drawer_hire").hide();
        $("#drawer_social").hide();

        lastBlock = ("#drawer_hire");


    $('.show_hide_about').click(function(){
        $("#drawer_about").slideToggle(700);
        $(lastBlock).hide(700);
        lastBlock = ("#drawer_about");
    });

    $('.show_hide_contact').click(function(){
        $("#drawer_contact").slideToggle(700);
        $(lastBlock).hide(700);
        lastBlock = ("#drawer_contact");
    });

    $('.show_hide_hire').click(function(){
        $("#drawer_hire").slideToggle(700);
        $(lastBlock).hide(700);
        lastBlock = ("#drawer_hire");
    });

    $('.show_hide_social').click(function(){
        $("#drawer_social").slideToggle(700);
        $(lastBlock).hide(700);
        lastBlock = ("#drawer_social");
    });
});
```

Am I going OTT here? is there a simpler way to do this?

The main problem I'm having is it all works, however if the ABOUT ME panel is open and the user clicks the HIRE ME link, I get a weird effect. What I'd want in this situation is for the ABOUT ME panel to fold up, then the HIRE ME panel to fold down.

Hope that makes sense, thanks folks,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set up the links like this: `<a href="" class="show" data-section="contact">asdf</a>`

Then you all you need is:

```
$('.show').click(function(ev) {
    var $visibleDrawer = $('.drawer:visible').eq(0); // make sure to get only one (or 0) drawer

    // set currentSection to the drawer's id or empty if no drawer was found
    var currentSection = $visibleDrawer.length?$visibleDrawer.attr('id').replace('drawer_',''):'';

    $('.drawer').slideUp(700);
    $('a.show').removeClass('active'); // reset all link classes


    (function(clickedSection, $link){ //<-- pass the active link to have access to it inside the closure
        if(currentSection != clickedSection){
            $link.addClass('active');        // set active class on clicked link
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#drawer_'+clickedSection).slideDown(700);
            }, ($visibleDrawer.length?700:0)); // set the timeout to 0 if no drawer visible
        }
    })($(this).data('section'),$(this)); //<--

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I'd have used `$.index()` myself, but this is better. +1

Comment: This is great, thanks so much for your response. I can see how it should work, and have implemented it exactly as you suggested, however the line:
`$('#drawer_'+$(this).data('section')).slideDown(700);` isn't working for some reason. I've put an alert in the `setTimeout` and that works, so it's just that one line isn't working for some reason? Thanks once again for your response, hope to hear back from you soon :)

Alex

Comment: @AlexCowley i updated the answer. My mistake, inside the setTimeout the `this` isn't to the `a` anymore, since the function creates a new context where `this` is the DOMWindow. So i wrapped it in a closure to pass the `a` element. You could just save the `a` in a variable like: `var $element = $(this);` before the timeout, but i tend to use closures in such situations as they're safer :)

Comment: Brilliant Andy, thanks very much. Only thing now is if the ABOUT panel is open, clicking the About link closes and then re-opens the panel again - is there any way I can stop this from happening, and just close the panel instead? Cheers bud!

Comment: @AlexCowley sure, i updated my code again. this should do it. first get the name of the currently visible section then, open the new one only if it's a different one

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy, really appreciate it! However, it seems like the second line isn't working for some reason? Thanks once again!

Comment: @AlexCowley how is it not working? can you do `alert(currentSection)` after that? Is it empty? I made a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/nbX5X/ and it alerts the correct section for me

Comment: The alert doesn't fire after that line - works before it though (displays as "undefined")

Comment: @AlexCowley do you get any errors in firebug or chrome dev tools?

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry for taking ages to reply, have had assignments to hand in in Uni.

Chrome Dev Tools is giving me this:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: @AlexCowley haha no problem. Oh right that looks like it's because at first no drawer is visible and it returns an empty set. I updated my answer again :)

Comment: Haha, you're a legend mate. Thanks so much. I'm going to be an awful person and ask one final little thing - is there any way I can eliminate the delay between the click and the drawer opening when no drawer is visible?

Kind of hard to explain. But it works beautifully, except when you click a link and no drawer is open, there is a delay before the drawer opens (I think it is because of the `setTimeout` part?). Thanks buddy!

Comment: I'll be even meaner and ask, is there any way I can change the selected link to indicate what's been picked? I tried to figure it out, and after `$('#drawer_'+clickedSection).slideDown(700);` I added `$('#link_'+clickedSection).css({"margin-left":"20px"});` (after adding an ID Tag on the links similar to the drawers) but this simply adds the margin and leaves it there forever, instead of toggling it. How would I go about sorting this?

Comment: @AlexCowley you'll have to reset the margin if another link is clicked. I updated the answer yet again. I chose to use a class to indicate the current link as i think it's cleaner. I also changed the timeout - this should set it to 0 if nothing is open :) Hope it works!

Comment: That's fantastic Andy! I noticed that the link doesn't remove the `active` class if you click it again to close the drawer - I tried doing this but it's not working, any idea how to go about it?

`if (this.hasClass('active'){$(this).removeClass('active');} else {$(this).addClass('active');}`

Comment: @AlexCowley i moved the addclass part inside the `if(currentSection != clickedSection){` block so it only gets active when it should.

Comment: Brilliant Andy. Thanks so much, this is fantastic. Do you have a website I can link to in the credits, seen as you've pretty much custom-written this script for me? :)

Comment: @AlexCowley Haha, no sorry. Thanks for the offer though. Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

using [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can parse a callback function which will be executed at the end of the  animation, or you can use [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to keep track of the point of execution against and element. Some pseudo code of the first way

```
$('#foo').animate(function() {
    // do stuff with foo
}, duration, easing, function() {
    $('#bar').animate(function() {
         // do stuff with bar
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8vD7D/2/) is a link to how it works on jsFiddle **(Note that you should choose framework to be jQuery)**

I think this would work with you :

```
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('.header').click(function(){
                //To hide all other contents
                $('.content').slideUp('slow');
                var num=$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
                //And show this one .. 
                $('#content_'+num).slideDown('slow');
            });

        }
    );
```

HTML should look like this :

```
                    <div class="header" id="title_111"><a href="#">Category 1</a></div>
                    <div class="content" id="content_111">

                    </div>

                    <div class="header" id="title_112"><a href="#">Category 2</a></div>
                    <div class="content" id="content_112">

                    </div>

                    <div class="header" id="title_113"><a href="#">Category 3</a></div>
                    <div class="content" id="content_113">

                    </div>

                    <div class="header" id="title_114"><a href="#">Category 4</a></div>
                    <div class="content" id="content_114">

                    </div>

                    <div class="header" id="title_115"><a href="#">Category 5</a></div>
                    <div class="content" id="content_115">

                    </div>

                    <div class="header" id="title_116"><a href="#">Category 6</a></div>
                    <div class="content" id="content_116">

                    </div>
```